# How do I add a platform to LibGdx project?

Tags: java, android, html, libgdx, desktop

I created a LibGdx Project with the LibGdx project creator tool. When I ran it, I selected Android and Desktop projects, but I did not add html. How can I add html support in my LibGdx game later?

Comment: Create new project. And copy core code into new one. :-)

Comment: Maybe there is some other way. But this is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

It has never happened to me, but try, libgdx project creator tool with the same name as the project that you have created but only for html in your path, then import Gradle proyect, bulding html and check only